# Unity Билд не заканчивается

Tags: unity3d, build, apk

Всем Привет, у меня проблема с игрой, не билдится, а просто зависает на Building Resources Folder
Я пробовал и перезапустить Юнити, и удалить заново скачать, менял версию по нескольку раз и даже новый пустой проэкт сделал, во всех местах, во всех проэктах такая проблема

Билды я делал и под APK и под ПК, во всех местах одно и тоже, никаких шейдеров, партиклов и других штук кроме моделей, префабов и скриптов в моём проэкте нет

Пробовал удалять некоторые файлы Юнити, такие как library и ProjectSettings, тоже не помогло, по документации от Юнити лазил по Player Settings, опять нечего

В адресе проэкта да и во всех местах нету русских букв, только английские символы

Тут ещё то что я месяц назад на этой же версии(на котором изначально был проэкт) сделал билд под APK, 3-4 раза и они сработали, а за это время я нечего не менял и не копалься в файлах Юнити

Вот скрин, 4 часа билда и нечего
Весь гугл обршарил, на русском и английском, ничто не помогает, уже не знаю что делать, в одном большом дискорд сервере так же поискал помощи, никакие советы не помогли[image: 4 Часа билда]

Comment: Какая у тебя версия Windows? Может быть проблема в нестабильном билде ос, которую ты используешь. Или же с жёстким диском проблемы. Если у тебя два жёстких диска, попробуй билдить на другой. В крайнем случае откатись до последней стабильной версии ОС с сохранением данных, авось прокатит

Comment: Попробуй собрать пустой проект.

Comment: @Nick Shakhrai ну можно попробовать над другой диск собрать, у меня билд на С делалься, попробую на Д, за совет спасибо)

Comment: @Qwer я пробовал собрать проэкт на пустом проэкте в 2 отдельных версиях, не помогло :(

Comment: @NickShakhrai дружище, СПАСИБО, ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ, я 2 дня ломал голову, 2 дня пречёсывал интернет как русский так и английский, и НОКАНЕЦ ТО, СМОГ, СПАСИБО БРАТ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалось решена благодаря человеку @Nick Shakhrai, за что ему ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО
Я просто создал новый проэкт на другом диске, и сбил его там же, сработало)